# How to extrude a polygon in a slope in CityEngine

Tags: 3d, cityengine, extrude

I am going to extrude polygons in slope using CityEngine and would like to have horizontal roofs. As you know, when you extrude a polygon in slope, a sloped roof is generated. But in reality buildings in slope have horizontal roofs.

What is the best approach to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably to create a horizontal polygon instead of a sloped one. Whether you want to have it touching the floor at the higher or the lower end (or the center) is your decision. Though I'd recommend to have the shape positioned in a way that the building is partially underground rather than partially flying.

When you created the shape to your liking you can also align the terrain to the shape so that your building is partially underground anymore.

Also worth a note is that CityEngine 2016.0 allows you to extrude along `world.y.flatTop` which does exactly what you want as far as I understand. For details see [this help page](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/cgareference/op_extrude.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you extrude along the world coordinate systems Y-axis

e.g.

Lot -->
     extrude(world.y, 10)

The above ensures that you use the Y-axis to extrude along and 10 being the value to extrude by.

Comment: This causes the same issue that I mentioned above. If you extrude by 10, you will have a slope roof. If you wanna have a horizontal roof, you should extrude some parts less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

like @gostefan stated CE 2016 does have world.up.flat, as stated in CE help docs, for getting flat tops. However for those who are trying this for a shapefile or other flat 2D polygon and are still using CE 2015.2 there is also a fairly simple solution. The trick is to basically set the *Align function* as *Translate to Minimum* when you are aligning the polygons to the slope.